# Running eclipse project on android device

Tags: eclipse, connection, usb, device

i'm new into programming for android. And i have few problems with connecting and debugging my eclipse project on android device - which is my phone Samsung Galaxy SIII. According to this  [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html) I tried to launch my app on my phone. Saddly when i press run button it tells me that there's no android device connected. And as you may know im not that dumm to not plug it into my computer. Additionally i have USB Debug mode ticked in options. My PC recognises it as "SAMSUNG Android ADB Device".

Some of you might say that i should start using emulator to have better view how this app will work on other phones/versions of android/etc. Thing is that my PC is quite old, and running an emulator makes it respond so slowly that it's nearly impossible to do anything on this emulated device. Plus... im quite sure that i wont publish this app on play store so i dont need to know if it will work on other devices. I just want to make a weather widget for me since stock one that uses accuweather.com tends to fail weather forecast for my country (like it says heavy rain on sunny day).

So here are the things that i have done so far to try to launch:
1. Uninstalled device and set some new drivers that should have helped me - saddly not ;]
2. Tried launching it via command line
3. I found somewhere on the Internet that it is possible to connect and test your app via WiFi using tcpip over 5555 port... saddly it failed too.

Any ideas what else should i try to make it work?

Comment: If this problem is still relevant to you: What system are you on? Have you tried if `adb` (Android Debug Bridge) sees your device (from command line run `adb devices`)?